# DBeaver: how to generate an ER diagram using the command line?

Tags: command-line-interface, entity-relationship, diagram, dbeaver

DBeaver has a very nice feature to generate an ER diagram from a live database. Is it possible to generate the diagram using the command line? I'd like to automate the process.

Comment: Since DBeaver can't do it, We solved the problem using the excellent open source SchemaCrawler: https://www.schemacrawler.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time, I am afraid that still is not possible, although there is an open [Github issue](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/6215) for exactly that purpose.